# UIAlertController Not Behaving as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to switch from ViewController A to ViewController B and show a message with a `UIAlertController` in ViewController B.

In my ViewController B I normally show my message like this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let alertMessage = String(format: "This is an alert!!")
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!", message: "This is an alert!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I switch from A to B like this:

```
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerTypeB
self.present(nextViewController, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

When I keep the code in ViewController B's `viewDidLoad()` as I have it above my alert does not appear and View Controller B is successfully switched to. One other thing I tried was changing the code in ViewController B's `viewDidLoad()` to:

```
let alertMessage = String(format: "This is an alert!!")
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!", message: "This is an alert!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))                        
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController!.present(alertController, animated: true,
                                completion: nil)
```

And now in this case when the code to go from A to B is called I see the alert shown on top of View Controller A, and View Controller B is never switched to.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should not try to `present` a view controller in `viewDidLoad()`. Try it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Don't you have an message in console? About presenting not in view hierarchy, or already presented?

Comment: @DonMag thanks! That was what I needed! Behaving as expected now

Answer (score 0):

A `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` is called, not when the view controller is displayed, but when it is loaded in the memory. If you wish to show an alert in ViewControllerB, you need to use `viewDidAppear` method for presenting your alert.

In case if ViewControllerB is not the last controller in your hierarchy, there may be an issue where the alert will be presented again when you come back to ViewControllerB after navigating to say ViewControllerC. In this case, you can maintain a `Bool` property which can keep track if ViewControllerB has appeared first time or not.